# xml flash banner with clicktag

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, clicktag

I have a flash banner that pulls in an xml with an image and a link.

I have set up the clicktag on a new layer with the following code

```
 on (release) {
 if (_root.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
    getURL(_root.clickTAG, "_blank");
  }
}
```

I need to somehow get this variable `dataArray[selItem].link` from the movie loading the xml and append it to the clicktag.

Comment: clickTAG is a way for the link to be controlled via FlashVars when the SWF is embedded. How are you loading the XML? What is the XML structure? Once you have the variable you can just concatenate the two strings with the "+" operator. ie getURL(_root.clickTAG + dataArray[selItem].link, "_blank");

Comment: I bought the flash from activeden. I did as you suggested previously and the publisher said that the click tag needed to be on another layer on top, but from there i can't access the variable dataArray[selItem].link.

Comment: you'll need to make it a _root variable: _root.dataArray... then you can access it from anywhere using _root....